# Racket if statement

Tags: if-statement, racket

I am trying to do an if statement whereby when the equation outputs an integer it returns the integer, and when the equation outputs an imaginary number, the if statement returns "no real roots".
This is the equation for which I need to write the if statement.

```
(define quadSolve 
  (lambda (a b c)
 (/ (+ (* -1 b)  (sqrt (- (sqr b) (* 4 a c)))) (* 2 a))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a temporary variable like this:

```scm
(let ((tmp expensive-expression))
  (if (complex? tmp)
      "no real roots"
      tmp))
```